# What are the essential COM components required for burning DVD in Windows XP using .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, com, components, dvd-burning

I'm trying to burn  DVD/CD through frontend C# code...

i have used IMAPI2 for buring CD/DVD in windows XP..but it is giving me unhandled exception... as:-

System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type 'IMAPI2.Interop.MsftFileSystemImageClass' to interface type 'IMAPI2.Interop.MsftFileSystemImage'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{7CFF842C-7E97-4807-8304-910DD8F7C051}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))

can anyone please help me out to solve this problem. I'm not able to solve this error. this project is working fine in Windows7 but unable to work with XP.

Comment: can u show the whole program code????????

Comment: you can see the code at //www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/imapi2.aspx ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMAPI2 is distributed with Vista or higher, XP comes with IMAPI, in which DVDs aren't supported. You can download IMAPI2 for XP [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932716).

Comment: can u tell me why this error is coming???
u can download the sample project from here:http: //www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/imapi2.aspx
and run this under the WindowsXP sp3 and if u r also getting the same eror then tell me the solution for this..

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in this because I'm starting a similar project. Anyway, it looks like the answer is at the page you linked to. Under the thread "BurnMedia application on XP SP3 not working ?", on page 2 of the comments, someone reports exactly the same error. Another poster states that he resolved it by changing:

```
[ComImport]
[CoClass(typeof(MsftFileSystemImageClass))]
[Guid("7CFF842C-7E97-4807-8304-910DD8F7C051")]
public interface MsftFileSystemImage : IFileSystemImage3, DFileSystemImage_Event
{
}
```

to

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("2C941FE1-975B-59BE-A960-9A2A262853A5")]
[CoClass(typeof(MsftFileSystemImageClass))]
public interface MsftFileSystemImage : IFileSystemImage, DFileSystemImage_Event
{
}
```

in one of the interop files.

However, on an even newer thread, the author suggests that this change (which reportedly works on Windows 7 and XP SP3) breaks Vista, and that he's working on a solution (as of a few days ago).